# "Then I ..." or "I then ..."

Tags: word-order

I would say that "then I ..." is the correct one, however

this guy uses

> "Then I put a dot ..."

only the first time here at 0:17

http://vimeo.com/13384698

the other times e.g. 0:23 or 0:38 he uses the form:

> "I then ..."

Are boths forms acceptable or should I use only **"Then I ..."** and stop using **"I then ..."**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In OP's examples, ***then*** means ***next***, [immediately] **after** [whatever time/event was previously mentioned].

The concept of [transitional tags](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/transitions.htm) seems useful here. Depending on your point of view, you could say ***then*** conveys either *addition* or *time sequence* - but I'll go for the latter, since that's obviously the category for related alternatives such as ***first, next, finally***.

My initial inclination was to say ***then*** can happily go before or after the subject (***I*** in OP's example), and leave it at that. But it's worth pointing out that although this is true, and applies equally to ***first*** and ***next***, it *doesn't* apply to ***finally*** in quite the same way...

> 1a: First I did this. 1b: Then/next I did that. 1c: Finally I did something else.
>   2a: I first did this. 2b: I then/next did that. 2c: ?I finally did something else.

There are some contexts where (2c) above is acceptable, but it doesn't really work in contexts where the *only* sense of ***finally*** is "next and last". If ***finally*** comes after the subject, there's invariably a strong implication of "next, and **at long last**".

I think what this suggests is that all these "transitional tags" should *normally come first* in the statement, but by custom and practice native speakers don't mind moving small short words to between the subject and verb. But because that's slightly "unusual" positioning, we tend to look for a possible semantic difference.

In practice there doesn't seem to be any credible semantic difference depending on whether we place ***then*** before or between subject/verb, so it's just a stylistic choice. But there certainly *can* be a subtle difference according to the position of ***then***...

> 3: *"You lost £1000 at the roulette table? I hope you **then** stopped gambling!"*
>    4: *"You lost £1000 at the roulette table? I hope you stopped gambling **then**!"*

In (3), ***then*** has the normal sense *(chronologically **after**)*, but in (4) it has the more "extended" sense of ***as a result*** [of what came before], **in that case, therefore**.

---

To summarise: there's no grammatic or semantic difference in OP's *specific* examples, but if you're looking for *general* principles, you'll be safer if you put any transitional tag *first* in a statement.

Finally, [here's an NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20then%20went%20home,Then%20I%20went%20home&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,I%20then%20went%20home;,c0;.t1;,Then%20I%20went%20home;,c0) showing how usage has shifted over the past couple of centuries.